# Problem in showing grid when using [pivotMode]="true" and [enableRtl]="true" together in ag grid

Tags: pivot, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I use ag grid with these properties:

```
  <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [pivotMode]="true"
    [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>
```

I  need my grid to be rigth to left, when I add [enableRtl]="true" to the ag grid, my grid do not show the data correctly.

How can I solve this problem?

Suggestions ?